# How to get tail result with line number

Tags: linux, tail

I tried to use `tail xxxx.log | nl` to get last 10 lines and their line numbers, but nl command only counts the lines of tailed result. Say there're 20 lines in that file, the returned result's actual line number should be from 11 to 20 which is what I want, but 1 to 10 is returned by this command.

Comment: `tail` has no way to know how many lines are in the file without reading it in its entirety.

Answer (score 3):

The issue that you are having is that you first run `tail`, and then number the resulting lines. This would always number the lines in the output from `tail` as 1 through to 10.

Swap the order of your commands, i.e. number all lines first with `nl`, then run `tail` on that:

```
nl xxxx.log | tail
```